# How to handle missing embedded expressions in template literals

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am wondering what the best approach is in using expressions in a template literal. The below code works fine

```
var val1 = "Hello"
var val2 = "world"

var template = `${val1} ${val2}!`
console.log(template)
```

But lets say for some reason there is no val2

```
var val1 = "Hello"


var template = `${val1} ${val2}!`
console.log(template)
```

in that case it will throw me an error like below

> var template = `${val1} ${val2}!`
>                             ^ ReferenceError: val2 is not defined

is there a way to define a default value or something so it does not throw an error ?

Comment: Uh, variables are not conditionally declared. What are you actually doing here? If you are abusing string interpolation for templating: use a real template engine instead.

Comment: i am using it for some email body to return info to user. Using ejs or handlebar would be an overkill

Comment: Can you show your actual code, please? In what way does "*there is no `val2`*" happen? Surely you don't miss to declare the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never leave variables undeclared. Instead use an object, and look up properties on it if you need dynamic props:

```
 const context = { val1: "hello" };
 // context.val2 = "world";
 var template = `${context.val1} ${context.val2}!`
```

That will result in `Hello undefined!`, if you want something else use the `||` operator:

```
 var template = `${context.val1} ${context.val2 || "world"}!`;
```

Comment: I was actually already using an object as my variables come from a db query and i pass them to function. I just made a simple sample. Did not know that it would treat the object different then simple variables and it allows me to just use ||"" just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so; this code will always throw that error:

```
var val1 = "Hello"
var template = `${val1} ${val2}!`

console.log(template)
```

Could you provide us with a more specific example of your use case? I assume this is inside of a function which is expecting a `null` or `undefined` value. If that's what's happening, then this might work:

```
function makeAString(val1 = '', val2 = '', val3 = '') {
   var template = `${val1} ${val2}!`
   console.log(template);
}

makeAString("Hello");
//logs "Hello !"
```

If you don't like the empty space, and you want something that is more reusable, you could do this:

```
function makeAString(vals = {}) {
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(vals)
    .filter(prop => !!vals[prop])
    .reduce((template, prop) => `${template} ${vals[prop]}`, "")
    .trim()
    .concat("!");
}

let stringValue = makeAString({
  val1: "Hello",
  otherValue: null,
  undefinedValue: undefined,
  val3: "there",
  val4: "Friend"
});
console.log(stringValue);

//logs "Hello there Friend!"
```

There is probably a better way to do it, but that's the first thing that came to mind.